# Count total number of http response in android Application

Tags: android

In my application i would come to know total number of HTTP request that is sent from device to server.
i have already tried that but i can't get proper solution.

How can i resolve this.? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If these are your own HTTP requests, count them yourself, using an `int` somewhere

If these are not your own HTTP requests, you have no ability to know that they are being made, and so therefore cannot count them.